# Laravel file max size validation with ajax

Tags: php, laravel, validation

I'm uploading data via axios to the backend which is in Laravel. In those data, I have an image sent. In my local dev environment (Homestead) everything works well, when I try to upload a picture greater dans 2048 KB, I receive from the backend an error stating that the files are too big.

Here's one of my validation string for a picture :

```
$this->validate($request, [
    ...
    'infrastructure_image' => 'image|max:2048|mimes:jpg,jpeg,png'
    ...
]);
```

Here I try to upload a picture bigger than 2048 KB :

[image: Here I try to upload a picture bigger than 2048 KB]

Here I try the same thing online (deployed on a server with Laravel Forge) :

[image: Here I try the same thing online (deployed on a server with Laravel Forge)]

So with the same code, I have two different results. At first, I thought that it might be a configuration of PHP and Homestead might be more permissive than on my production server. So I changed all the values regarding upload of a file to, for example, not be less than 2048KB which would result in a 413 error.

Now I have in the PHP-FPM php.ini file :

`post_max_size = 8M`

`upload_max_filesize = 8M`

I restarted PHP-FPM trough Forge.

Still same error.

Am I missing something here? How could this give me two different results with the same code?

One thing I realized also, is that in local, it seems the file is not uploaded (might be a false impression since upload is really faster in local -> local). But when uploading on the website, I see the file being uploaded. Isn't that the point not to upload the file is too big? Or whatever happens, the post request send the file (not just its information) then Laravel checks the size and returns errors if the file is too big.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/forge/413-request-entity-too-large-nginx162

Comment: it is a server configuration issue.

Comment: what you mean is that on production it's ignoring laravel validation rule 'max' right?

Comment: Yes, it was indeed a server configuration issue, Thanks to @RossWilson for the link to the solution !